# jQuery - Own plugin - need small help

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I created my own jQuery plugin in 1.4 and now I need a small amount of help.

```
$.etrade = function()
{

}
```

I need so I can build code like this

```
$.etrade = function()
{
    this.var = 'setting';

    this.subfunction = function()
    {
    };
}
```

when I take function from my plugin I need to use it like this:

```
$.etrade.var = '5';
$.etrade.subfunction();
```

Somebody know what I mean? and how I can get this problem done? :)

Comment: that isn't jQuery at all. it's just bad written javascript. why don't you explain us in more detail what are you trying to achieve? there doesn't seem to be any defined logic in your snippet.

Comment: Careful not to sound too mean, gonchuki!

Comment: But, yes, NeoNmaN, it's not clear from your example what you're trying to do, or why you want to write a jQuery plugin at all, rather than just writing a bit of javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to assign a plain old object to `$.etrade`, not a `function`. Like this:

```
$.etrade = {
    variable: 'setting',
    otherVariable: 'something else',
    subfunction: function () { /* do stuff here */ },
    anotherSubFunction: function () { /* do other stuff here */ }
}
```

That said, I'm not sure how this qualifies as a jQuery plugin, since it looks like you're just tacking an ad-hoc property onto `jQuery`.

Aside: you can't use `var` as per your example, since it's a keyword in JavaScript.

Comment: i know var its a keyword, its only a example, :) so, if i need more subfunction so i only need newfunction: function(){} ?

Comment: @NeoN: okay, just making sure. Re: more subfunctions- yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: will you plase make a sample :0) so im 100% understand. :)

Comment: @NeoN: sure, check my edit. Is that what you were looking for?